# Assigning certain scopes of an application to a subset of users in AAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm looking into using Azure AD for our applications. One important aspect is the ability to allow only a subset of users certain scopes (`scp` claim in the JWT) for some applications. Therefore I'm looking for a solution to assign those scopes through groups, roles or similar, but haven't found any information whether this is possible or not.

As an example there are two applications (AppA, AppB). In AppA all users should have the scope `MyResource.Delete`, but in AppB only a small subset of users should have the scope `MyResource.Delete`. All users should have access to both apps, but the permissions within those apps should differ.

How would I manage such a setup through AAD?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve that with scopes. But you can achieve that with [application roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles).

Once you [define application roles for your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#more-information), you can [assign only specific users to speific roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/methods-for-assigning-users-and-groups). This is the way to fine control access to the application and control which user what type of access they have.

**UPDATE**

This is now possible using the new preview feature - [Admin Consent Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow). This feature allows individual users to request consent which can be approved by administrators. Once approved, only those users will be granted consent to required scopes.